# Angular Reactive Forms - FormArray and pacthValue

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I'm having trouble using patchValue with formArray.
I have a custom select made with `<ul>`, `<li>`, the click on an option executes a method that should patch the id of the option selected in an `<input type="hidden" />` that will contain the value of the property in the formarray.

This is how the form is built:

```js
  this.roleForm = this.fb.group({
    profiles: this.fb.array([ this.fb.group({perfil: '', accion: ''}) ])
  })
```

This is the method to add new profiles in the array:

```js
  addProfile() {
    const prof = this.roleForm.get('profiles') as FormArray;
    prof.push(this.fb.group({
      perfil: [''],
      accion: ['']
    }))
  }
```

And this is the html:

```html
<div class="col-md-8" formArrayName="profiles">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let profile of getProfiles(); let i = index">
    <div class="col-md-6" [formGroupName]="i">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card card-primary bg-white">
          <div class="card-header h4">
            Perfil
          </div>
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush register h5 scroll-list">
            <li *ngFor="let profileType of profileTypes; index as i" 
                class="list-group-item rounded-0 pointer" 
                [ngClass]="{'selected bg-primary text-white font-weight-bold': this.selectedProfile === profileType.profileId}" 
                (click)="selectProfile(profileType.profileId, i)">
              {{profileType.profileDescription}}
            </li>
          </ul>
          <input formControlName="perfil" type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

I'd have to use patchValue in this method to set the selected value in the input with the same index. But I can't make the at() method work, this always returns me an undefined:

```
selectProfile(profileType.profileId, i) {
 let x = (<FormArray>this.roleForm.get('profiles')).at(i);
 console.log(x)
}
```

Comment: How and where are you using `patchValue`? Can you post that method?

Comment: Problem is not clear. Its better if you can also create an stackblitz

Comment: NOTE: pacthValue NOT add new elements to the array, you need call to your funciton addProfile or a function to remove elements of the array before make pacthValue

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question with an edit describing the exact problem I'm having

Comment: what is `profileTypes`? looks like `roleForm.profiles` isn't in sync with whatever that is

Comment: @bryan60 that's just the ngfor with the data that builds the custom select. The formarray profiles is supposed to wrap that select.

Comment: see my answer, you double declared `i`, which is why you're probably getting undefined when you try to access the form control at `i` since `i` isn't what you expect

Comment: @bryan60 I posted just that code because i think my error is in how im using the formarray, cause i cant make the at(i) work.

Comment: clearly we're having trouble communicating, the reason `at(i)` isn't working is because you have duplicate `i` declarations in your template and you're sending the wrong `i` to your function

Comment: @bryan60 no, sorry, i answered you the previous comment without noticing your reply. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm guessing your problem is a duplicate declaration of template variable `i`:

```
<div class="col-md-8" formArrayName="profiles">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let profile of getProfiles(); let outterI = index"> <!-- declared here -->
    <div class="col-md-6" [formGroupName]="outterI">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card card-primary bg-white">
          <div class="card-header h4">
            Perfil
          </div>
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush register h5 scroll-list">
            <!-- and here -->
            <li *ngFor="let profileType of profileTypes; index as innerI" 
                class="list-group-item rounded-0 pointer" 
                [ngClass]="{'selected bg-primary text-white font-weight-bold': this.selectedProfile === profileType.profileId}" 
                (click)="selectProfile(profileType.profileId, outterI)">
              {{profileType.profileDescription}}
            </li>
          </ul>
          <input formControlName="perfil" type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you don't need to declare an index variable when using a `ngFor` though if you're not using it, as you don't seem to be using `innerI` in this example.

Comment: Thank you, @bryan60 I could resolve my issue with you making me notice my silly mistake handling the indexes.